# Laravel - Google line chart not displaying

Tags: laravel, charts, google-visualization

I create a line chart where it shows a total sales by a date but it return an error 'Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string'. I check my viewsource and it return a right data for my line chart. I don't really know whats the problem. Can anyone help me with this, on how to display the chart?

My viewsoure data

```
["18th April 2020","64.50"],["19th April 2020","91.00"],["20th April 2020","644.70"],["21st April 2020","120.50"]
```

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class LaravelGoogleGraph extends Controller
{

  function index()
    {
      $data = DB::table('booking_detail')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('sum(total_price) as sums'), 
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date_sell,'%D %M %Y') as months"))
        ->groupBy('months')
        ->get();
     $array[] = ['Date', 'Sales'];
     foreach($data as $key => $value)
     {
      $array[++$key] = [$value->months, $value->sums];
     }
     return view('google_pie_chart')->with('months', json_encode($array));
    }
}
?>
```

My blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Make Google Pie Chart in Laravel</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <style type="text/css">
       .box{
        width:600px; height:400px;
       }
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       var analytics = <?php echo $months; ?>

       google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

       google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

       function drawChart()
       {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
        var options = {
         title : 'Booking Sales'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
       }
      </script>
  </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">Booking Report</h3><br />
   
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h3 class="panel-title">Booking Sales</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" align="center">
     <div id="line_chart" style="width:550px; height:350px;">

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I solve it already, seem like my sum return value as string instead of int/float. I add "+=0" inside the array statement for sums at the controller $array[++$key] = [$value->months, $value->sums+=0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the values for the line should be numbers, not strings...

remove the quotes around the second value in each row,
change...

```
["18th April 2020","64.50"]
```

to...

```
["18th April 2020",64.50]
```

---

also, [arrayToDataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable) has a second, optional boolean argument...

> `opt_firstRowIsData` - Whether the first row defines a header row or not. If true, all rows are assumed to be data. If false, the first row is assumed to be a header row, and the values are assigned as column labels. Default is false.

if the first row in the array does not represent column headings,
then you should include `true` as the second argument, here...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics, true);
```